# Only 923 MB out of 4 GB RAM showing on Windows 10 HP laptop

Tags: windows-10, memory

I have Windows 10 32-bit installed on my laptop ([HP Pavilion G7](https://www.cnet.com/products/hp-pavilion-g7/specs/)) with a single 4 GB stick of RAM. But the system only reports 932 MB of memory. I have tried removing the module and putting it back.

Output of `wmic memorychip list full`:

```
BankLabel=BANK 1
Capacity=4294967296 
DataWidth=64 
Description=Physical Memory 
DeviceLocator=Bottom-Slot 2(under)
FormFactor=12
HotSwappable= 
InstallDate= 
InterleaveDataDepth=1 
InterleavePosition=2 
Manufacturer=A-DATA Technology 
MemoryType=24 
Model=
Name=Physical Memory 
OtherIdentifyingInfo= 
PartNumber=AM1U16BC4P2-B19H
PositionInRow=1
PoweredOn= 
Removable=
Replaceable= 
SerialNumber=00004EB9 
SKU= 
Speed=1333
Status= 
Tag=Physical Memory 1 
TotalWidth=64 
TypeDetail=128
Version=
```

This question is different from the marked duplicate because there are **3 out of 4 GB missing!**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71903/discussion-on-question-by-olga-only-923-mb-out-of-4-gb-ram-showing-on-windows-10).

Answer (score 3):

Your BIOS either does not support, or is not configured to support, a 32-bit OS. Most of the address space below 4GB is reserved for hardware devices that cannot access addresses above 4GB. The BIOS has remapped your memory above the 4GB mark to make room for such hardware mappings.

If your BIOS supports 32-bit OSes, you need to figure out how to enable that support. Usually it's an option called "memory remapping" that you turn OFF. But it could be something else.

If your BIOS doesn't support 32-bit OSes, use a 64-bit OS. I can't find anything that says your laptop supports 32-bit OSes and it wouldn't be a good idea to install one even if it did.

Comment: If this is correct (as I suspect it is), this is a notably different answer than those given by the question this post was originally marked a duplicate of.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator Yeah, the people who marked it as a duplicate probably didn't actually read it. That's why everyone voted to re-open it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Holy cow, then that means Ramhound voted as duplicate without reading it.... I thought that was unheard of with that guy!! LOL ... https://i.imgur.com/ifgiq68.png . . . If you're reading Ramhound, what comes around goes around.... j/k... Lions, tigers, and RHEL.... oh my!!